# ModelMapper - Illegal SourceGetter error when defining a explicit mapping

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

**Part1**

I am using the Java ModelMapper library (http://modelmapper.org/) to manage the mappings between my entities and DTOs. I have a Contact (entity) and a ContactView (DTO).
I have a string field in ContactView that doesn't exist in Contact called "type".
Its value should be just the name of the entity's subclass.
I have tried to make this custom mapping like this:

```
modelMapper.typeMap(Contact.class, ContactView.class).addMappings(mapper -> {   
   mapper.map(src -> src.getClass().getSimpleName(), ContactView::setType);
});
```

I get a compilation error at:
mapper.map(src -> src.getClass().getSimpleName(), ContactView::setType);

> Illegal SourceGetter defined
>
> 1 error   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]   ... 33 common frames omitted

I even tried using a Converter, same result:

```
modelMapper.typeMap(Contact.class, ContactView.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
  Converter<Class, String> toName = ctx -> ctx.getSource() == null ? null : ctx.getSource().getSimpleName();
  mapper.using(toName).map(Contact::getClass, ContactView::setType);
});
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

**Part 2**

Following up the proposed answer, I tried to add a Converter Class to the ModelMapper. This is where I configure the ModelMapper Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Mapper {
    @Autowired
    private ContactTypeRepository contactTypeRepository;

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper getMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

        modelMapper.typeMap(ContactTag.class, ReferenceEntityView.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
            mapper.map(src -> src.getTag().getCode(), ReferenceEntityView::setCode);
            mapper.map(src -> src.getTag().getValue(), ReferenceEntityView::setValue);
        });

        modelMapper.typeMap(Person.class, PersonView.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
            mapper.skip(PersonView::setName);
            mapper.map(Person::getName, PersonView::setLastName);
        });

        modelMapper.addConverter(new ContactConverter());

        return modelMapper;
    }

    class ContactConverter implements Converter<Contact, ContactView>  {
        private ModelMapper localMapper = new ModelMapper();

        @Override
        public ContactView convert(MappingContext<Contact, ContactView> context) {
            Contact contact = context.getSource();
            ContactView contactView = localMapper.map(contact, ContactView.class);
            ContactType contactType = contactTypeRepository.getByCode(context.getSource().getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase());
            contactView.setType(localMapper.map(contactType, ReferenceEntityView.class));
            return contactView;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I use the ModelMapper Bean to generate my DTO:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts")
public class ContactController {
    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ContactView findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        Contact c = contactRepository.getOne(id);
        ContactView cv = modelMapper.map(c, ContactView.class);
        return cv;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the convert method from the Converter is not called and the "type" field from the ContactView object is null. The other mappings on the ModelMapper Bean are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the implementation of ModelMapper

```
 public boolean isValid(M member) {
  return !Modifier.isStatic(member.getModifiers()) && !member.isSynthetic();
}
```

And the documentation for isSynthetic method says

> Returns true if this member was introduced by the compiler; returns
> false otherwise. Returns: true if and only if this member was
> introduced by the compiler.

I guess that is why it fails an exception.

For a similar case we introduced a specific mapper class use modelMapper as base mapper and set the other field:

```
 class ContactMapper{
 ...
 public ContactView toView(Contact contact){
 ContactView contactView = modelMapper.map(contact,ContactView.class);
 contactView.setType(contact.getClass().getSimpleName());
 return contactView;
 }
```

To make it consistent with the overall mapping you can define this as a converter and register it to your mapping like this

```
class ContactConverter implements Converter<Contact, ContactView>  {
        private final ModelMapper localMapper = new ModelMapper();

        @Override
        public ContactView convert(MappingContext<Contact, ContactView> context) {
            Contact contact = context.getSource();
            ContactView contactView = localMapper.map(contact, ContactView.class);
            contactView.setType(contact.getClass().getSimpleName());
            return contactView;
        }
    }

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.addConverter(new ContactConverter());
```

Comment: Thanks cool. So basically we do the custom mapping outside the ModelMapper, after we get the DTO object from it. Despite we are not keeping the mapping logic only under the ModelMapper, in this case is not worrisome. But what if I have a similar problem with the ContactView's children (for instance, a contact can have multiple addresses). Do you suggest to iterate over them after the ModelMapper returns the DTO? It doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: You are right dr. fatca. We are also using converter for it. I attached an example.

Comment: I tried the example attached but for some reason the converter is not executed. I added a breakpoint inside the convert method, which is not reached when I execute: _ContactView cv = modelMapper.map(c, ContactView.class)_. cv.type is also null

Comment: are you sure that you added converter into modelmapper ?

Comment: I believe so. I attached the code in the part 2 of the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, it seems the framework never executes the Converters. I added this new mapping with and it is never called:

Comment: `modelMapper.typeMap(Contact.class, ContactSearchResultView.class).addMappings(mapper -> {
            Converter<List<Address>, String> toAddress = ctx -> {
                List<Address> addresses = ctx.getSource();
                if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0){
                    return addresses.get(0).address1;
                }
                return null;
            };
            mapper.using(toAddress).map(src -> src.getAddresses(), ContactSearchResultView::setAddress);
        });`

Answer (score -1):

Try my library [beanknife](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife). It's a annotation processor. It means jdk will generate the class for you before you compile the project. So it do the work at compile time. You can use the generated class like any other classes you write yourselives. And you can see the source of the generated class, So no more magic.
This library is able to generate the DTO class for you. You don't need change the original class. In addition to configuring annotations on the original class, you can also choose to create a new configuration class and configure annotations on top of that. The library supports copying and inheriting all properties of the original class, and removing modifying or adding properties base on that. For your question:

```
// this will generate a DTO class named "ContactView". 
// (This is the default name which just append 'View') 
// You can change this name using genName attribute.
@ViewOf(value=Contact.class, includePattern = ".*")
public class ContactViewConfigure {
    // Add a new property. 
    // Make sure there is no property named 'type' already in Contact. 
    // Or you need use @OverrideViewProperty
    // There are multi way to add new property.
    // In this way, you use a public static method accept the original class instance as the unique argument. 
    // The new property name is decide by the attribute 'type' of @NewViewProperty. 
    // So the method name is not important.
    @NewViewProperty("type")
    public static String type(Contact contact) {
        return contact.getClass().getSimpleName()
    }
}

// This is the generated class.
public class ContactView {
    // other properties
    ...
    private String type;
    // getters and setters (By default only getters are generated)
    ...
    // many constructors
    ...
    public static ContactView read(Contact source) {
        ContactView out = new ContactView();
        // initialize other properties
        ...
        out.type = ContactViewConfigure.type(source);
        // initialize other properties
        ...
        return out;
    }

    // other read method, such as read list, set and map.
    ...
    // other generated methods
    ...
}

// use like this.
Contact contact = ...
ContactView dto = ContactView.read(contact);
```

In some situations, beanknife is much powerful than ModelMapper. For example, if something wrong happened, you can check the source of the generated class (Usually located in /target/generated-source/annotations, may differ on IDE), and see why. If it really a bug, you can commit issue to the github, I will deal with it as soon as possible.

Here are more [examples](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife/tree/master/beanknife-examples/src/main/java/io/github/vipcxj/beanknife/cases/beans).

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. This seems very promising, though, I was able to move forward with ModelMapper. I updated the version of the library and did a lot of refactoring on how my mappings and converters were coded. If in the future I find more problems and a decision is made to replace MM, I will give a look on your solution.

Comment: ModelMapper and some other mapping libraries focus on mapping data structures, while beanknife focuses on generating DTOs. Although There are some overlap function between them, they have different focuses. For the existing DTO, it is more convenient to use the mapping library, but if you want to add a new DTO, beanknife is more suitable. But beanknife and ModelMapper can work together without conflicting each other